# Библиотека pymem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymem

**Код:**

```
import pymem

shellcode = '''
f = open("hello world", "w")
f.write("pymem_injection")
f.close()
'''

pm = pymem.Pymem("notepad.exe")
pm.inject_python_interpreter()
pm.inject_python_shellcode(shellcode)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 53-55: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня ваш код работает без ошибок, возможно вам стоит указать **encoding="utf-8"** в функции **open()**

```
import pymem

shellcode = '''
f = open("hello world", "w", encoding="utf-8")
f.write("pymem_injection")
f.close()
'''

pm = pymem.Pymem("notepad.exe")
pm.inject_python_interpreter()
pm.inject_python_shellcode(shellcode)
```